# Is there a way to do a cyclic convolution analytically in Mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, convolution

Let's say I want to convolve a Gaussian function

```
Pulse[t_] = Exp[-(t - Mid)^2/(2 sig^2)];
```

with an exponential broadening function

```
ExpBroad[t_] = time^-1 Exp[-t/tau] UnitStep[t];
```

I can do this analytically by using the `Convolve` function, or I can turn them into discrete lists and use `ListConvolve`.

For `ListConvolve` I can compute the cyclic convolution:

```
Conv = ListConvolve[Pulselist, Explist, 1]
```

by using the option `1`.

Is there an analog for this analytically?

Comment: Cyclic convolution is equivalent to having a periodic function.  So you simply need to define  `ExpBroad` as periodic.

Answer (score 3):

First, I assume you have a typo with `time^-1` and that it should be `1/\[Tau]`.  Second, let me *strongly* recommend you never ever use variables that start with a capital, lest you inadvertently invoke a function.

```
myPulse[t_, μ_, σ_] := Exp[-(t - μ)^2/(2 σ^2)];

myExpBroad[t_, τ_] := 1/τ Exp[-t/τ] UnitStep[t];

Assuming[τ > 0, 
 Integrate[
           myPulse[t, μ, σ] myExpBroad[t - tt, τ], 
      {tt, -∞, +∞}]
          ]
```

$e^{-\frac{(t-\mu )^2}{2 \sigma ^2}}$

Answer (score 0):

ListConvolve can be used to solve the cyclic convolution(循环卷积).
Principal value interval of the cyclic convolution  is equal to

```
   CyclicConvolution[lis1_, lis2_] := ListConvolve[lis1, lis2, {1, 1}]
   CyclicConvolution[{1, 2, 0, 1}, {2, 2, 1, 1}]
```

> {6, 7, 6, 5}

If you want to solve this in hand,you can use the following approach:
[image]